# ¿Cuál es la forma correcta de evaluar el Progreso de un Proceso? C#

Tags: c#, windows-forms, visual-studio-2010, progressbar

Tengo un proceso en el cual hago evaluaciones de los empleados, para procesar los ponches, en el formulario de X cantidad de empleados que se muestren el usuario puede seleccionar los que desea procesar. Mientras esta procesando debo mostrar el Progreso y porcentaje que va transcrurriendo el proceso.

**Problema:** El `progressBar` va aumentamento pero el `labelPorcentaje` no aumenta, solo muestra el 100% al finalizar el proceso. La Cantidad de datos a procesar depende de los empleados que seleccione el usuario, por lo tanto en ocaciones pueden ser pocos o muchos, quiero poder apreciar el aumento del progreso durante el proceso sin importar que sean pocos o muchos los datos a procesar.

He hecho un ejemplo sencillo para representar mi problema:

```
private void btnEvaluar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      labelProgreso.Visible = true;
      progressBar1.Visible = true;

      int progreso = 0, porciento = 0, totalEmpleadosProcesar = 0;

      for (int indice = 0; indice < 85; indice++) //Ciclo que representará los empleados seleccionados
      {
          totalEmpleadosProcesar = 85;  //Total de Empleados que seleccionó el usuario

          progreso++; //Aumentando el progreso 
          porciento = Convert.ToInt16(( ( (double)progreso / (double)totalEmpleadosProcesar ) * 100.00 )); //Calculo del porcentaje

          reportarProgreso(100, porciento); //función que cargará la barra de progreso

          //MessageBox.Show("Porciento: " + porciento);
      }

      MessageBox.Show("Completo...");
      labelProgreso.Visible = false;
      progressBar1.Visible = false;
}
```

Función que carga el ProgressBar:

```
private void reportarProgreso(int valorMaximo, int valor)
{
     progressBar1.Step = 1;
     progressBar1.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Continuous;
     progressBar1.Minimum = 0;
     progressBar1.Maximum = valorMaximo;

     if (valor > valorMaximo)
     {
         labelProgreso.Text = "100%";
         progressBar1.Value = valorMaximo;
     }
     else
     {
         labelProgreso.Text = Convert.ToString(valor) + "%";
         progressBar1.Value = valor;
     }
 }
```

Para solucionarlo intenté usar `Thread.Sleep(1000);` durante el recorrido del ciclo, pero de igual forma no muestra el porcentaje en el `label`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> No deseo utilizar un `Thread.Sleep` porque como expresé si son pocos empleados funcionaría bien, pero si son muchos y tengo un tiempo establecido para el Thread se tardaría un montón.

Si intervengo cada interacción del ciclo con un `MessageBox` de prueba si me muestra el porcentaje en el `label`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**¿Qué estoy haciendo mal? , Cual sería la forma correcta de representar el progreso de un proceso?**

**Nota**: No me interesa que la interfaz siga estando activa durante el proceso, por eso no he utilizado `Task` o `BackGroundWorker`...

Entorno: Visual Studio 2010 (WindowsForms) & .NET NetFramework 4.0

Comment: "No me interesa que la interfaz siga estando activa durante el proceso, por eso no he utilizado Task o BackGroundWorker..." justamente, ese es el problema.. la interfaz no esta activa, con lo cual el label no se va a refrescar. el progress si porque tiene vida propia.

Comment: En todos los casos donde deba utilizar `progressBar` y un `label` para representar el porcentaje, debo utilizar eso `BackGroundWorker` entonces? :( **Que otra opción tengo?**

Comment: no. backgroundworker no. Usa await y task. y la otra opcion es no refrescar el label :p.. c# no tiene un doevents (cosa que si tenia VB)

Comment: @gbianchi es que aún no logro engancharme al funcionamiento del `Await` y `Task` no logro entenderlo es complicado para mi.

Comment: Si se puede refrescar un label cuando este no es creado en el hilo que haces ese cambio.

Comment: @DarielRamosDíazdeVillegas , pero en este caso solo estoy trabajando con un hilo, cuando estoy con varios hilos, utilizo `delegado` e `InvokeRequired` para actualizar el `label` que no pertenece al hilo principal, pero en este caso, Como debería hacerlo?

Comment: @Pikoh pues tendré que implementarlo así, ya que no se usar `Await` y `Task` , ¿Cuando se usa el `BackGroundWorker` es obligatorio programar  todo lo que tiene que ver con `RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs` y `CancellationPending`,?

Comment: @Pikoh, ok muéstrame un ejemplo en que no tenga que programar todo en `RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs` y demás métodos. Te pregunt sobre el `CancellationPending` porque si al momento que se esta ejecutando el proceso el usuario cierra el formulario sin que el proceso se halla detenido puede provocar un error ya sea por `Dispose` o algo por el estilo, **Esto no causaría problema?**

Comment: He añadido mi respuesta. En principio, no habría ningun problema al cerrar el formulario, pero tampoco quería ir yo tan en profundidad. Pruebalo de todas maneras, y si tienes algun problema o duda me comentas

Comment: @gbianchi Ha un tiempo coloqué una pregunta y pusiste un ejemplo de `Task` pero la verdad no lo entendí bien. Basado en este proceso especifico, puedes colocar un ejemplo usando `Task` y `Await`  a modo de aprendizaje? si no te molesta.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El problema es que tu bucle bloquea el hilo principal de ejecución,haciendo que no se redibuje el label. Yo para solucionarlo recomiendo usar un BackgroundWorker.

Primero, define el `BackgroundWorker` en tu formulario:

```
BackgroundWorker bg = new BackgroundWorker();
```

Luego en el evento del boton, configuras los eventos `ProgressChanged`, `DoWork` y `RunWorkerCompleted`y llamas a su ejecución:

```
private void btnEvaluar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bg.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    bg.ProgressChanged += bg_ProgressChanged;
    bg.DoWork += bg_DoWork;
    bg.RunWorkerCompleted += bg_RunWorkerCompleted;
    bg.RunWorkerAsync();
    labelProgreso.Visible = true;
    progressBar1.Visible = true;
}
```

Evento `DoWork` (he añadido un `Sleep` para que se aprecie el progreso) :

```
private void bg_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    int progreso = 0, porciento = 0, totalEmpleadosProcesar = 0;

    for (int indice = 0; indice < 85; indice++) //Ciclo que representará los empleados seleccionados
    {
        totalEmpleadosProcesar = 85;  //Total de Empleados que seleccionó el usuario

        progreso++; //Aumentando el progreso 
        porciento = Convert.ToInt16((((double)progreso / (double)totalEmpleadosProcesar) * 100.00)); //Calculo del porcentaje
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
        bg.ReportProgress(porciento);
    }
}
```

El evento `ProgressChanged` donde actualizamos tanto el `Progressbar` como el `Label`:

```
private void bg_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // Change the value of the ProgressBar to the BackgroundWorker progress.
    progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    progressBar1.Step = 1;
    progressBar1.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Continuous;
    progressBar1.Minimum = 0;
    progressBar1.Maximum = 100;

    if (e.ProgressPercentage > 100)
    {
        labelProgreso.Text = "100%";
        progressBar1.Value = progressBar1.Maximum;
    }
    else
    {
        labelProgreso.Text = Convert.ToString(e.ProgressPercentage) + "%";
        progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    }
}
```

Por último, el evento `RunWorkerCompleted` que se ejecuta cuando el `BackgroundWorker` ha finalizado:

```
private void bg_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Completo...");
    labelProgreso.Visible = false;
    progressBar1.Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: He probado tengo un problema, y un inconveniente, **problema:** al finalizar el proceso luego del `MessageBox` da error porque se esta tratando de cambiar la visibilidad del label y progress desde otro hilo (Pero esto se como resolverlo), **Inconveniente:** Si se fija detenidamente el mensaje de "Completo..."  lo muestra antes de que la barra de progreso este cargada en su totalidad, Hay como resolver eso? aunque no es un problema grave pero al ojo del usuario no debería verse de esta forma. Debería completar la barra y luego mostrar el mensaje.

Comment: @J.Rodríguez fallo mio (por no probar el código). Eso debes implementarlo en el evento `RunWorkerCompleted`. Ahora edito la respuesta

Comment: @J.Rodríguez ya está. Fijate que en el evento del boton enlazo el evento `bg.RunWorkerCompleted += bg_RunWorkerCompleted;`  y luego en el manejador del evento pongo las lineas problematicas y las quito del `DoWork`

Comment: @Pikoh, una sugerencia también puede ser: en lugar de usar `progressBar1.Value = 100;` se pude usar: `progressBar1.Value = progressBar1.Maximun;`.

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave bien visto, aunque la propiedad es `Maximum` y no `MaximumValue` :)

Comment: @Pikoh si tenia pensado eso para resolver el problema de cambiar objetos de otro hilo, pero aun sigo apreciando que el `Mensaje` lo muestra antes de completar por completo, por ejemplo : el `Label` llega a 100% muestra el mensaje y luego completa el `progressBar` en su totalidad, aunque es poco el tiempo lo puedo ver, Se podrá solucionar esto?

Comment: @Pikoh bueno será... Otra pregunta relacionada a este proceso, si en algún momento deseo usar esto en otro proceso, donde deba implementar un `Botón` para `Pausar/Reanudar` el proceso se puede realizar con `BackGroundWorker` ?

Comment: @Pikoh probé con un proceso pesado que consume mucho datos, y de todos modos el mensaje de completado se muestra antes de que la barra se cargue por completo :(

Comment: @J.Rodríguez ok,mañana hago una prueba y te miro como solucionarlo. Ya te digo algo

Comment: @Pikoh esta bien, por favor pero no olvides revisarlo

Comment: @J.Rodríguez he hecho un programa de prueba, y funciona correctamente. El único efecto que se nota es que, si el proceso es demasiado rápido(sleep(20), este es mas rápido que la animación del progress y no le da tiempo a la animación a finalizar antes que el progreso, pero si te fijas en el label, hasta que no llega a 100% no sale la ventana de completado. Lamentablemente creo que no hay manera de esperar por la animación. Si el proceso es mas largo, sin embargo (sleep(1000)), si que la animación acaba al mismo tiempo que se lanza el diálogo.

Comment: @J.Rodríguez sospecho que la animación del cambio de progreso progressbar se lanza en otro hilo y se van "encolando". Si se pasan muy deprisa estos progresos, la animación no tiene tiempo de finalizar antes de que se lance el evento. Creo que no hay solución sencilla para ello(o yo al menos la desconozco)

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74246/discussion-between-j-rodriguez-and-pikoh).

Answer (score 1):

Lo que a mi me resultó y lo escribo por si alguien como yo viene buscando ayuda al respecto.

EL bucle anda congelando el Hilo principal de la actividad. Entonces lo hay que hacer es enviar el tema del bucle a un nuevo hilo con Thread. EL ejemplo es al subir una foto de perfil a Storage de Firebase. El while comprobaba si ya había link para enviar al imageView, como el subir la imagen tomaba unos segundos, EL bucle while congela todo. De la siguiente forma me funcionó. Aclaro que solo estoy mostrando la parte del código que puse dentro del Thread.

```
new Thread(
                () -> {
                    while (!uriTask.isSuccessful());

                    if(uriTask.isSuccessful()){
                        uriTask.addOnSuccessListener(uri1 -> {
                            String url = uri1.toString();
                            String id = uidTaxista.getText().toString();
                            cargarUrlFoto(url, id);
                        });
                    }
                    Log.d("FileManager", "uploadImg OK!");
                }
        ).start();
```